# App authentication refresh

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

i have been trying new authentication, but sometimes happens that on first acces app is refreshing again and again. (I mean when no cookies are set..first time ever or for example after browser restart)

I have this code for authentication:

```
require_once './facebook/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
          'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'], 
          'fileUpload' => $fbconfig['fileUpload'],
          'cookie' => true,
        ));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if($uid)
{
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['me']))
  {
     try
        {
           $_SESSION['me'] = fql("select name, sex, pic_big, locale, email, birthday from user where uid=me()",$facebook);
           $_SESSION['me'] = $_SESSION['me'][0];
        }
        catch(Exception $o)
        {
          print_r($o);
        }
  }
}
else
{
            $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                array(
                    'scope'         => $fbconfig['perms'],
                    'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['canvas'],
                )
             ); 
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
            exit;
}
```

So error is $facebook->getUser(); it is 0. but when i stop refreshing and go there again..it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting P3P headers. Some browsers won't allow a page in an iframe to set a cookie unless they are specified.

Something like this as the first line in the PHP should do it.

header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');

More info on P3P here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P